# AppleScript - Move all the files contained in subfolder to a top folder

Tags: applescript

I am looking for an edit to the current script. What I need is moving all the files from subfolders (recursively) in to one top folder, however if a file with the same name exist, create a new top-folder and continue there, this is what I have so far:

```
tell application "Finder"
    try
        set Random_name to random number from 100 to 9999
        set theTopFolder to (choose folder)
        set theFiles to a reference to every file of (entire contents of folder theTopFolder)
        set theNewFolder to make new folder at theTopFolder with properties {name:"Flattened Files"}
        move theFiles to theNewFolder
    on error
        set theNewFolder to make new folder at theTopFolder with properties {name:"Flattened Files" & Random_name}
        move theFiles to theNewFolder
    end try


end tell
```

Just to be clear the structure of the path is not:

Mainfolder/subfolder/file.xxx but Mainfolder/subfolder/sulbfolder2/subfolder3/....100/file.xxx so the script needs to work recursively which it does but it stops when a file exist with the same name

When a file with the same name exist my edit creates a new folder with Flattened Files+random number however when another file with the same name is moved the script stops for an error instead going ahead and creating a new Flattened Files+randonnumber folder. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: So you are wanting to make a new folder for a duplicate name instead of just adding a suffix?  What do you want to do if you wind up with multiple fils or top folders with the same name?

Comment: hey @red_menace thanks for your reply. What I am looking for is folders Flattened Files1, Flattened Files2, Flattened Files3 and so on, containing all the files of the subfolders. Of course in case there are no duplicates Flattened Files1 should contain all the files. Yes is important that the name of the files are not touched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script isn't using recursion, it just lets the Finder get all the files.  The additional error you are getting is because you are trying to move the whole list of files again.

One solution would be to step through the file items, testing for duplicates as you go, and make new folders as needed.  The following script just moves duplicates to added folders (note that an error will still stop the script).  I don't know how you are sorting the file list, so I included a line to uncomment to continue moving file items to the added folder.

```
set theTopFolder to (choose folder)
tell application "Finder"
    set theNewFolder to make new folder at theTopFolder with properties {name:"Flattened Files"}
    set theFiles to every file of (entire contents of folder theTopFolder) as alias list
    repeat with aFile in theFiles
        if file ((theNewFolder as text) & (name of aFile)) exists then -- use added folders for duplicates
            set counter to 1
            set done to false
            repeat until done
                set suffix to text -2 thru -1 of ("000000" & counter) -- leading zeros for sorting
                set alternateFolder to (theTopFolder as text) & "Flattened Files" & space & suffix
                tell me to (do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of POSIX path of alternateFolder) -- make new folder as needed
                if file (alternateFolder & ":" & (name of aFile)) exists then -- continue to next one
                    set counter to counter + 1
                else
                    move aFile to folder alternateFolder
                    # set theNewFolder to folder alternateFolder -- uncomment to continue moving here after a duplicate
                    set done to true
                end if
            end repeat
        else
            move aFile to folder (theNewFolder as text)
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Hi @red_menace and thank you for the script. Your version is working fine, just to be sure that I understood properly: If I want the script to keep moving the files to Fattened Files 01 until a new duplicate is found I need to remove the comment to that line?

Comment: Correct.  I didn't have that many files to test with so I'm not sure what the purpose is or how well that is going to work with the normal Finder arrangement (there isn't much of a guarantee of file order without some kind of sorting), but you mentioned doing that in your original post.